# Date field not recognized with Azure Form Recognizer

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I have built a custom neural model using the Form Recognizer Studio. I have marked the date fields when I labeled the data to build the model.

I have problems extracting the exact date value using the following Java SDK:

> com.azure:azure-ai-formrecognizer:4.0.0-beta.5

The returned JSON (as previewed in the Form Recognizer Studio) is:

```
"Start Date": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "content": "01.05.2022",
                    "boundingRegions": [
                        {
                            "pageNumber": 1,
                            "polygon": [
                                1.6025,
                                4.0802,
                                2.148,
                                4.0802,
                                2.148,
                                4.1613,
                                1.6025,
                                4.1613
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "confidence": 0.981,
                    "spans": [
                        {
                            "offset": 910,
                            "length": 10
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

If I am using the Java SDK, then the **getValueDate()** returns null, while the **getContent()** returns the correct string value.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue occurs because the document I use is not in English and the date format might not be recognized. As per documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/language-support only English is supported for custom neural models.